# Find max value and its coordinates in 2D array through parallel processing

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing

Given the following bit of code, which performs a pretty straightforward task:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 181; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
    {
        if (Arr[i][j] > Max)
        {
            Max = Arr[i][j];
            MaxPosition[0] = i;             
            MaxPosition[1] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

and provided that using `mutex`es takes more time than leaving this like it is, is there any other possibility to do the same in a parallel loop? I can think of `atomic` and `combinable` to find `Max`'s value, but not to obtain it's position in the `Arr` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have X parallel threads each checking a small partition of `Arr`, then you can have X `MaxPosition` arrays and an array of X `Max` values. Then when the parallel threads are all done, you have a small loop to find out the final max value from the `Max` array, using the position from the `MaxPosition` arrays.

---

Simple example:

```
void thread_function(int start_x, int end_x,
                     std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& arr,
                     int& max_value,
                     std::pair<int, int>& max_position)
{
    max_value = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

    for (int x = start_x; x < end_x; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 360; ++y)
        {
            if (arr[x][y] > max_value)
            {
                max_value = arr[x][y];
                max_positions.first = x;
                max_positions.second = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now how to use it

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;  // The array of numbers, filled with values somehow...

constexpr size_t number_of_threads = 4;

std::vector<int> max_values(number_of_threads);
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> max_positions(number_of_threads);

// Initial values
int start_x = 0;
int end_x = arr.size() / number_of_threads;

std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
{
    threads.emplace_back(thread_function,
                         start_x, start_y, std::cref(arr),
                         std::ref(max_values[i]),
                         std::ref(max_positions[i]));
}

// Wait for threads to finish
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_threads; ++i)
{
    threads[i].join();
}

// Now max_values contains the max value for each thread
// and max_positions contains the positions for that value from each thread

// Collate the data
auto iter_pos = std::max_element(begin(max_values), end(max_values));

int max_value = *iter_pos;
std::pair<int, int> max_position = max_positions[std::distance(begin(max_values), iter_pos)];

std::cout << "The max value is " << max_value << ", and it is found as position <" << max_position.first << ',' << max_position.second << ">\n";
```

***Notes:***

The code above requires that the number of elements in the "first" dimension is evenly dividable by `number_of_threads`. For example `180` would work, but not `181`. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to fix that.

For references to the classes and functions used, please see e.g. [this superb online C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: I'm still unsure how to put that `if` in a parallel processing structure. I do get the logic, but sadly there is no example on the internet

Comment: @Noldor130884 Made a quick example. Adapt after your needs.

Comment: @Noldor130884 If you have access to a C++17 compiler then you could replace all my code and just use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) directly using a custom comparator and a `parallel_policy` [execution policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t).